# python правильно передать ссылку на экземпляр объекта

Tags: python, многопоточность

Прошу прощения, у меня не получилось написать тему вопроса более понятно и коротко.

У меня есть класс Configs (паттерн singletone) в котором централизовано содержатся все настройки приложения. Приложение многопоточное (около 7-9 независимых потоков). В каждый из них я передаю единственный экземпляр класса Сonfigs.

Я хочу, изменив данные в Configs в одном из потоков, видеть все те же изменения в других потоках. То есть мне надо иметь один экземпляр настроек, который при этом видят и могут менять все другие потоки.
На данный момент сделано примерно так:

```
@Singleton
class Configs:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg = 1
        self.ip_table = 2 #Пример каких-то данных
```

Далее в главном потоке, который запускает все остальные:

```
app_data = Configs.Instance()
thread1 = cs.Server(app_data)
...
thread7 = cs.Server(app_data) #На самом деле все потоки принадлежат к разным классам
thread1.start()
...
thread7.start()
```

Внутри, например, первого потока thread1 меняется параметр:

```
self.app_data.cfg = 3
```

После этого, он должен автоматически стать таким же и в других потоках (на самом деле параметры изменяются более глобально). Я думал, что паттерн Singleton решит мою проблему и всё произойдёт именно так, но похоже, что когда я передаю в класс экзмепляр другого класса как параметр, то этот экзмепляр становится новым объектом.
А мне надо, чтобы все потоки ссылались на один и тот же объект Configs.
Я помню, что как-то это делалось, но к сожалению забыл как. Пожалуйста, подскажите!

Comment: Из приведённых примеров получается, что параметр действительно должен автоматически стать таким же в других потоках, причём вообще независимо от того, синглтон оно или нет. (А ещё оно не очень потокобезопасно, но это не по сути вопроса.) Так что нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример с проблемой

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал уважаемый @andreymal, должно работать. Я проверил id всех ссылок (передаваемых в параметре) на этот объект, и они оказались одинаковыми.
Я эффект, при котором у меня не менялось значение, хотя должно было, оказался связан с тем, что код "непотокобезопасен".

Подправив логику, я увидел, что всё работает. Спасибо.